# Remove mobile detection from web forms site template in VS 2017 using vb.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, webforms

I have a site that I built using the vb.net web forms template in VS 2017.  I would like to remove the detection of mobile devices and serving different web pages based on mobile or desktop since I am using bootstrap and my main site.master looks good on mobile and desktop.

I have tried following the suggestions on this site and others including:

Removing the Site.mobile.master, removing the viewswitcher.ascx file, etc.

None of the methods fully work.  The one that comes the closest to working is commenting out the line "RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes)" in the global.asax.vb file.  When I do that, it serves the right default page to all browsers and all pages correctly to desktop browsers but all other site pages are missing on mobile devices and I get "The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable." instead.

Can anyone tell me how to disable this.  It should be possible to just fix the code so that it just assumes all devices are non-mobile as a work around but I can't find where to do that.

Comment: We don't have the code that you're using. You'll need to go through your site and figure out what's necessary and what's not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone ends up here with the same problem I figure out a very simple solution.  I found that mobile detection is deeply embedded in many different places in the web app template and it was proving very challenging to find all of those places.  Therefore instead of rooting it out, I ended up telling the app to serve the normal master page to both desktop and mobile browsers by making the site.mobile.master file the same as the site.master file. I just copied the entire content of the site.master.aspx file and replaced the content of the site.mobile.master.aspx file with it.  It took about 15 seconds and works perfect.